# PowerShell workflow doesn't work in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, powershell-workflow

I have a script in PowerShell. It's running from Jenkins via a PowerShell step.  Without Jenkins all works fine. But when I build it with Jenkins, I got nothing... no errors, just nothing. What's wrong? Jenkins can't use PowerShell workflow?

Simple example:

```
workflow config {
    Param([string[]]$servers, $MaxEnvSize, $MaxMemPerShell)

    $servers = $servers.Trim()

    foreach -parallel -throttlelimit 50 ($server in $servers) {
        if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1) {
            inlinescript {
                try {
                    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $using:server -ea Stop  -ScriptBlock {
                        Param($MaxEnvSize, $MaxMemPerShell)

                        Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\MaxEnvelopeSizekb -EA Stop -Value $MaxEnvSize
                        Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Shell\MaxMemoryPerShellMB -EA Stop $MaxMemPerShell
                        Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Plugin\Microsoft.PowerShell\Quotas\MaxMemoryPerShellMB -EA Stop $MaxMemPerShell
                        #Restart-Service winrm
                    } -ArgumentList $using:MaxEnvSize , $using:MaxMemPerShell
                } catch {
                    "$using:server : $Error[0].Exception"
                }
            }
        } else {
            Write-Output "$server no ping"
        }
    }
}

config -Servers $env:servers -MaxEnvSize 16454  -MaxMemPerShell 5192
```

Comment: Keep in mind that Jenkins is running as the System user and (likely) not the user with which you are testing. I found it easiest to just call a .bat command and run "PowerShell.exe -Command "& 'path\to\powershell_script'"

Comment: I can use the cred, but this does not change anything. I can make it so that the jenkins on the slave run from under the domain user, but this also does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

By default jenkins will use 32-bit powershell. Powershell workflow is supported only in 64-bit powershell. trigger powershell script using C:\Windows\Sysnative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe which will redirect to 64-bit powershell.